# The method 'call' isn't defined for the type 'BookListFoodMenuState'.Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method

Tags: flutter

The method 'call' isn't defined for the type 'BookList FoodMenuState'.\Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'call'
**How to call function Call in my Food class on Column?**

 My Class

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'class_list_food.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class MyCard {
  final String name, desc, image, flav;
  final double price;

  MyCard(
      {required this.name,
      required this.desc,
      required this.image,
      required this.flav,
      required this.price});
  factory MyCard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MyCardFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MyCardToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Food extends MyCard {
  @override
  final String name, desc, image, flav;
  @override
  final double price;

  Food(
      {required this.name,
      required this.desc,
      required this.image,
      required this.flav,
      required this.price})
      : super(name: name, desc: desc, image: image, flav: flav, price: price);

  factory Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FoodFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> foodtoJson() => _$FoodToJson(this);

  static var foodList = [];

  void call() async {
    final foodRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('listfood').withConverter<Food>(
              fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Food.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
              toFirestore: (food, _) => food.foodtoJson(),
            );

    /*await foodRef.add(Food(
      name: 'Mandarine',
      desc:
          'We have been loading up on the stone fruit and berries at the market.',
      price: 53,
      image: 'assets/images/food2.png',
      flav: 'Caramel Flavour Sweet Ice Cream',
    )); //adding a sample document for testing
*/

    await foodRef.get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            foodList.add(Food(
              name: doc["name"],
              desc: doc["desc"],
              price: double.parse(doc["price"]),
              image: doc["image"],
              flav: doc["flav"],
            ));
          })
        });
    }
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Beverage extends MyCard {
  @override
  final String name, desc, image, flav;
  @override
  final double price;

  Beverage(
      {required this.name,
      required this.desc,
      required this.image,
      required this.flav,
      required this.price})
      : super(name: name, desc: desc, image: image, flav: flav, price: price);

  factory Beverage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$BeverageFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> foodtoJson() => _$BeverageToJson(this);
  static var beverageList = [
    Beverage(
      name: 'test',
      desc: 'We have test',
      image: 'assets/images/food1.png',
      price: 3.0,
      flav: 'Strawberry test',
    ),
  ];
}
```

**Example widget to call Call() but it gives error**
If I can call this part then I can fetch index data from database and insert data instead. Food.foodList.length but i can't call call() please help me or suggest a better way

```
class BookListFoodMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget categories;
  const BookListFoodMenu({Key? key, required this.categories})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BookListFoodMenu> createState() => _BookListFoodMenuState();
}

class _BookListFoodMenuState extends State<BookListFoodMenu> {
  
  String dropdownValue = 'TH';
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
            onPressed: () {
              //Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              //   builder: (BuildContext context) => MyApp()));
            },
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: dropdownValue,
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = newValue!;
                  });
                },
                items: <String>['TH', 'EN', 'CN', 'TW']
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              )),
        ],
        title:
            const Text("อาหารภาคเหนือ", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Mitr')),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 72,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 12),
                    Text(user.displayName!,
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Mitr')),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              widget.categories,
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "Popular",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontFamily: 'Mitr',
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/filter.png",
                          width: 22,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          /*Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => const BookAllListPopular()));
                    */
                        }),
                        call(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                height: 315,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: Food.foodList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final food = Food.foodList[index];
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) {
                              return DetailFood(food: food);
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 0),
                        width: 225,
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          color: const Color(0xffFBCEDC),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Image.asset(
                                  food.image,
                                  width: 150,
                                  height: 130,
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      food.name,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Mitr',
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      food.flav,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Mitr',
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 15,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "\$" + food.price.toString(),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Mitr',
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `call()` is a method of the class `Food`, so you need an instance of that class to call the method.

However, just like `Food.foodList` you could make is `static` and call it via the class name: `Food.call();`

You may also need to call `setState()` after you call completes to update the UI.

FWIW, you should try to use a proper state management technique to improve your program.